# Strange assignment in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array A with n rows of size 3. Each row is composed by three integers, each one  is a integer which refers to another position inside the numpy array. For example If I want the rows refered by `N[4]`, I use `N[N[4]]`. Visually:

```
N = np.array([[2, 3, 6], [12, 6, 9], [3, 10, 7], [8, 5, 6], [3, 1, 0] ... ])
N[4] = [3, 1 ,0]
N[N[4]] = [[8, 5, 6]
           [12, 6, 9]
           [2, 3, 6]]
```

I am building a function that modifies N, and I need to modify N[N[x]] for some specified x which is a parameter too (4 in the example). I want to change all the 6 in the subarray for another number (let's say 0), so I use numpy.where to find the indexes, which are

```
where_is_6 = np.where(N[N[4]] == 6)
```

Now, if I replace directly like `N[N[4]][where_is_6] = 0` there is no change. If I make a previous reference like `var = N[N[4]]` and then `var[where_is_6]` the change is done but locally to the function and N is not changed globally. What can I do in this case? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The indexing with another indexing won't work with the way you have defined your list `N`. You need to have N converted to `numpy.array()` first.

Comment: I said it was a numpy array, the code although doesn't reflect that, editing right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to convert the indices to the original `N`'s coordinates:

```
row_idxs = N[4]
r,c = np.where(N[row_idxs] == 6)
N[row_idxs[r],c] = 0
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I'll be thinking in that way next time I need to modify things.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `N[N[4]]` is a new array, which you can check doing:

```
print(N[N[4]].flags)

C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

where `OWNDATA` shows this fact.

Comment: Thanks for the .flags tip! Then what can I do to make the change?

Comment: @AlejandroSazo well... perimosocordiae's answer seems to be a good solution